# How do i open Angularjs app in jQuery dialog?

Tags: angularjs

I have written an AngularJS app which works just fine when launching it from browser. But when i try to  launch the same app within jQuery dialog from one of my app, it never runs. I see the app loading all the scripts in Chrome developer toolbar but it never hits the debugger; statement in the app.run method. Am i missing something here?

Following is how i am trying to launch my app using jQuery dialog:

```
            var windowWidth = $(window).width()-40;
            var windowHeight = $(window).height()-40;

            $("#div").load('<link to my angular app>').dialog({ modal: true, height: windowHeight, width: windowWidth, title: "Angular App" });
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Instead create an ngController and insert `ng-controller="controller_name"` in your HTML. Angular will handle the DOM insertion. With Angularjs, you should never have to use jQuery to inject anything into your DOM. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @J.P.Armstrong: My Angular app is just a module of another application. This other application is my Main/Parent application which is developed in ASP.NET web forms. What you see in the post is an example of launching the AngularApp(SPA Module) from Main Application. My main application knows nothing about Anuglar. This is why i used jQuery dialog to launch SPA Module in a dialog.

Comment: Sorry, I can't imagine using AngularJS for just a dialog. You may be over engineering this and is bound to lead to more problems in the future.